# Photodiode transimpedance amplifier with integrated filtering

Tags: transimpedance

In a previous question about transimpedance amplifier stability, one interesting suggestion was that instead of trying to do multiple stages of op-amps in order to provide equalization for my signal, I should consider trying to integrate the filtering into the transimpedance stage itself rather than as a second, following stage.

Here is one possible way to do that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdcnZs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Essentially, it is a normal transimpedance amplifier with feedback capacitance preceded by a current divider.  At high frequency, the inductor L1 is an open circuit, and the TIA works like a normal TIA receiving most of the photocurrent.  At lower frequencies, the inductor passes current, attenuating the signal.  By tuning the values of L1 and R6, I could move the corner frequency around and equalize the photodiode impulse response.  I have a couple of questions:

1. This seems like a fairly simple idea, and intuitively I would expect the inductor to have no affect on stability (or the value of C1) because its impedance will be high at frequencies where the phase margin decreases but I couldn't find much about doing this on Google, which makes me worried that I have missed some obvious reason this won't work.
2. If I use a bipolar opamp, am I likely to have trouble with the relatively small value of R4 needed to balance the input voltages caused by the offset current?
3. The series resistor R5 will introduce a voltage drop when current flows, resulting in the photodiode seeing a smaller reverse bias.  Presumably this will introduce distortion at high current, but is there some way I can estimate how much current is tolerable (or equivalently how small I need to keep R5 to maintain reasonable linearity)?

Comment: *effect is the spelling you are looking for in this case. A reason you might not have seen this is that we try really hard to avoid using inductors. They're...not nearly as ideal as capacitors. You could probably do what you are asking for with just a properly sized DC block capacitor.

Comment: @DKNguyen I used an inductor here since I didn't want to block DC but you could also build filters out of capacitive elements (although some might involve presenting a high source capacitance to the opamp which would change its stability).